# Как организовать верстку одинаковых страниц на сайте?

Tags: php, шаблоны, вёрстка

Привет. Почти все сайты имеют общие части, одинаковые для всех страниц. Мой вопрос в том, как технически правильнее и удобнее делать одинаковые части. Допустим у разных страниц разная только середина кода, начало и конец одинаковые. Тогда можно:
а) Не делать ничего, каждая страница будет иметь свой одинаковый код. Тогда если понадобится что-то заменить, придётся править все страницы сайта. Когда их больше 15 это уже вызывает некоторые сложности.
б) как я обычно делаю:

```
<body>
<?php require('top.php'); ?>
код страницы
<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

В принципе этот способ всем хорош, но я сомневаюсь, что он правильный.
в) были какие-то php функции, не помню какие, там ещё вся страница была одним кодом, а в уникальные места вставлялись куски кода, сами уникальные места обозначались %. Этот способ мне не нравился, какие-то там были минусы, не помню уже.
г) есть ещё какой-нибудь способ, я уверен.
Помогите выбрать, как лучше сделать такую вёрстку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно делать примерно так:

index.php

```
<?php
include "router.php";
```

router.php

```
<?php
function not_found($path) {
     header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
     echo "<h1>404</h1>";
     die ("page not found! - $path -");
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) $path=preg_replace('#^/|/$|\.\.#','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //fixme подумать насчет секурности здесь.

if ($path=="") $path="main";
if (!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/pages/".$path.".php")) not_found($path);
include dirname(__FILE__)."/header.php";
include dirname(__FILE__)."/pages/".$path.".php";
include dirname(__FILE__)."/footer.php";
```

.htaccess (если апач, для других серверов по другому немного и REQUEST_URI в файле выше надо изменить

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php
```

- pages/main.php - контент главной страница
- header.php - header
- footer.php - footer
- pages/sample.php - какой нить еще контент, как назовете так и будет. обращаться как `http://mysite.org/sample/`

суть в следующем - перенаправляем **все** запросы на router.php который решает какой файл показывать в контенте.

**Код выше лучше понять прежде чем использовать. Это *пример* как делать роутер а не код который рекомендуется копипастить.**

[тут демо с history.js](http://doduts.comoj.com/)

[исходник демки](http://doduts.comoj.com/archive.tar.gz)

Comment: ну конкретно у этого - отсутсвие кэширования на html (можно сделать, можно вообще весь роутер реализовать в .htaccess) ещё куча, это же не полноценный фреймворк.

Comment: ну не ради вас, я просто для демонстрации history.js демо писал, а сюда тоже подходит. секурность - надо быть уверенным что с помощью спец созданного REQUEST_URI не получится сделать запрос к другим файлом, кроме как из директории pages

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.  
Ещё один вопрос: file_exists'у пофиг что ли, что ему такой адрес дают:  
C:\xampp\htdocs\archive/pages/other.php? я про слеши

Comment: А этого не знаю, под винду не пишу. проверьте

Comment: Работает, но всё равно странновато... Ладно, спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Надеюсь мой вопрос будет замечен.. У меня почему-то не получается отловить отдельно ajax запросы и не обрабатывать их, вот это не работает   
    function is_ajax() {
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') return true;
}

Comment: и "не обрабатывать" ? в смысле надо `is_ajax() && exit;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Есть один проект, посещаемость 200 000 в сутки. Там используется подключение именно require (потому что парсить шаблоны с всякими %псевдотегами% накладно). Все вы правильно делаете.

Comment: И я вот думаю, что в принципе это чистый способ. Просто каждый сайт содержит одинаковый кусок кода, что и требуется...

Comment: обычно темлейтные движки делают прикомпиляцию темплейтов, так-что %% не накладно.